Confusion about type deduction in variadic templates
I have a class with multiple constructors, one being variadic and one taking an additional callable before the variadic arguments. However, the objects I create result in overload resolutions I dont understand. Here's my snippet:
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Test 
{
    std::function<void()> func;
    
    template<class... Args>
    Test(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Variadic" << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<class... Args>
    Test(decltype(func) newfunc, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Variadic with a callable" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    auto l = [](){};
    
    Test t{1,2,3}; //As expected
    
    Test t2{l, 1,2,3}; //Not as expected
    
    Test t3{{l}, 1,2,3}; //As expected, but why???
    
    //Same test, just with temporary
    Test t4{[](){}, 1,2,3}; 
    
    Test t5{{[](){}}, 1,2,3}; 
    
    return 0;
}

The output from this program (Both gcc and MSVC) is
Variadic
Variadic
Variadic with a callable
Variadic
Variadic with a callable
The first call makes perfect sense, but I would expect call 2 to result in the one taking a callable since std::function objects can be created from lambdas. However, it doesnt, but as soon as I wrap that lambda in another pair of braces in case 3, essentially converting it to an initializer_list with 1 element, the correct constructor is invoked. What I dont understand is why case 2 does not result in the 2nd overload being chosen and why making it an initializer list changes this behavior.

I would also recommend a good c++ book. as it will explain how overload resolution works.

a lambda is not std::function, it is convertible_to one.
when the compiler sees a variadic function of the form
template<class... Args>
    Test(Args&&... args)
...
template<class... Args>
    Test(std::function<void()> newfunc, Args&&... args)
...
Test t4{[](){}, 1,2,3}; 

the first one is a perfect fit, it doesn't require any cast, the second one requires a cast from a lambda to std::function, so the first one is chosen by overload resolution.
in the third case,
Test t3{{l}, 1,2,3}; 

the braces {l} are calling a an implicit conversion then passing the result to the function, so the compiler has to find an overload that requires an implicit conversion, so it decides to call the std::function constructor, then do ADL, which results in the second function to be the perfect fit because it is more specialized than function 1 and no cast is required, the first one doesn't require an implicit conversion so it doesn't participate in ADL.
refer to Implicit conversion sequence in list-initialization for how the compiler picks the best implicit conversion to do.
you can break this by applying a concept, or use enable_if with SFINAE and is_convertible
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <concepts>


template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleTofunc = std::convertible_to<T,std::function<void()>>;

struct Test 
{
    std::function<void()> func;

    template<class... Args>
    Test(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Variadic" << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<ConvertibleTofunc Arg, class... Args>
    Test(Arg&& newfunc, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Variadic with a callable" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto l = [](){};

    Test t{1,2,3};
    
    Test t2{l, 1,2,3};
    
    //Same test, just with temporary
    Test t4{[](){}, 1,2,3}; 
   
    return 0;
}

Variadic
Variadic with a callable
Variadic with a callable


Ohhh, so the braces around the passed lambda did not make an initializer_list out of it but instead a called the std::function constructor. That is tricky. That explains it of course

@Philipp317 it is constructing an initializer list, but it is not an std::initializer_list, it is instead an initializer list that has to be resolved to a constructor before the function is called.

@Philipp317 i think you need to read about Implicit conversion sequence in list-initialization it explains it better than i can, basically this list initialization enforces implicit conversion and std::function is chosen, your function doesn't have an overload that takes std::initializer_list as first parameter, if it did it would be ambiguous, but list initialization doesn't produce an initializer_list unless the function takes one.

"the braces {l} are ..". {..} has no types, and cannot be deduced with T&&, so only second overload is a (viable) candidate.
